# Boolean operations and binary protocol definitions within data type constraints in Arduino or C

Tags: c, arduino, binary

I'm building a binary protocol to handle `n` number of 10 bit analog input values. I'm trying to find a way to best accomodate a series of 10 bit values with a data type that makes it easy to perform boolean operations on. For example,

```
int main() {

    int array[] = {1024,343,512,256,223};
    char output[7];   

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        int addition = (array[i] << (10*1));
        output = output && addition;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        int printval = ((output >> (10*1)) && 0b1111111111);
        // this code is not working but should convey the idea with the intended output being the array elements in order.
        printf("Array %d: %d\n", i, printval);
    }
}
```

If I were able to set the size of a variable to 7 bytes like I have done with output which is enough to store 5 10bit data types, and able to perform the bitshift against the masked elements of the array the following could work.

More simply put, I have 5 variables, in this example we'll say they're 4 bits long; 1101, 1011, 1111, 0010, 0001 and I wish to put them together such that they stored sequentially in a byte/char array so in this instance

```
array[0] = 11011011
array[1] = 11110010
array[2] = 00010000
```

And write a means to extract the data of `n` bits based on its position (not element, but bit position) in the array, where each variable of data that needs to be extracted is 10 bits.

Comment: "data that needs to be extracted is 10 bits." --> I'd expect `& 0b1111111111`, not `&& 0b1111111111`  (one `&`)